# weird postgresql query runnning on aws postgres db

Tags: postgresql

got this weird query on my postgres aws server

```
SELECT
    ix.relname AS index_name,
    upper(am.amname) AS index_algorithm,
    indisunique AS is_unique,
    REPLACE(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid), ' WHERE .+', ''), '.*\((.*)\)', '\1'), ' ', '') AS column_name,
    CASE WHEN position(' WHERE ' IN pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)) > 0 THEN
        regexp_replace(pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid), '.+WHERE ', '')
    ELSE
        ''
    END AS condition
FROM
    pg_index i
    JOIN pg_class t ON t.oid = i.indrelid
    JOIN pg_class ix ON ix.oid = i.indexrelid
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON t.relnamespace = n.oid
    JOIN pg_am AS am ON ix.relam = am.oid
WHERE
    t.relname = 'sms_verif'
    AND n.nspname = 'public'
    AND indisprimary = FALSE;
```

anyone ever got this weird query running ? is this somekind of malicious query ? thanks for the help in advance

Comment: paste the output of the query when you run it on your own machine

Comment: only column name(index_name,index_algorithm,is_unique,column_name,condition) with 0 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the kind of query that would be run by a DB management tool, such as PgAdmin or DBeaver, so that it can populate its navigation pane with a list of database objects or offer a context menu when a specific object has been drilled down into.  It does not appear to be malicious, although it is possible someone could be using such a tool maliciously.

Comment: after got this message again, i think its what you said and this query are generated from my db gui. thanks for the help